# Django Form View not receiving data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using [Django Form View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) to split a large, single-page form into a multi-page form with separate templates for each one.  I followed the documentation and other online examples, and most everything is going well.

However, the problem is that I have required fields in the form and they are failing validation because, as it turns out, the data is not being passed back to Django (as was verified by overriding 'is_valid()' and printing the form data, as well as printing {{ wizard.form.errors }} in my templates).  It may be worth noting that the form worked fine *before* I split it up.

Below is a shortened version of the relevant code. If anyone has some pointers that would be great.  I am no expert at this and the original code was not written by me, so I'll answer any questions as best I can. Thanks!:

**VIEWS.PY**

```
FORMS = [("venue", RegisterBusinessFormVenue),
         ("manager", RegisterBusinessFormManager),
         ("extras", RegisterBusinessFormExtras)]

TEMPLATES = {"venue": "registrationVenue.html",
             "manager": "registrationManager.html",
             "extras": "registrationExtras.html"}


class RegisterBusinessView(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join('/var/www/', 'logos'))

    def get_template_names(self):
        return TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('submission_page_view'))
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class RegisterBusinessFormVenue(forms.Form):
    venue_name = forms.CharField(label='Venue Name', max_length=128)

class RegisterBusinessFormManager(forms.Form):
    manager_first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=255)

class RegisterBusinessFormExtras(forms.Form):
     website = forms.URLField(label="Website", required=False)
```

**URLS.PY**

```
 url(r'^register/', RegisterBusinessView.as_view(FORMS), name='register_business_view')
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block stylesheet %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/registration.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}

{% block content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Register your business</h1>
</div>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {{ wizard.form.errors}}
    {{ wizard.form.non_field_errors}}
    <legend>Event Venue Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group required {% if wizard.form.venue_name.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="inputVenueName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ wizard.form.venue_name.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   name="{{ wizard.form.venue_name.name }}"
                   id="inputVenueName"
                   {% if wizard.form.venue_name.value %}value="{{ wizard.form.venue_name.value }}"{% endif %}
                   placeholder="Venue name where events are held"
                   spellcheck="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="register-btn-block">
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.  It was a dumb mistake on my part: I wasn't using the wizard provided id's and name's for my html markup.  In my template above where I have the 'label for' and 'id' attributes, they should be populated with the value '{{ wizard.form.venue_name.id_for_label }}'.  For the 'name' attribute, it should be populated with '{{ wizard.form.venue_name.html_name }}'.

The pre-defined values that can be used are found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).  After making these changes, then the form data was properly submitted to the server.